# Cid in images not working while sending mail with inline images

Tags: node.js, base64, nodemailer, inline-images

I have a mail body with an inline image set as following:

```
<img src="cid:<<content-id>>">
```

I am using `nodemailer` to send mails. I also have a relative URL to the image. But the image is not being displayed in Outlook. Seems like `cid` is not working with recent versions of Outlook.

Other options?

Is it possible to get `base64` of the image in nodejs. I have seen example with `canvas` and `xmlhttprequest` but that can't be done in node without using external modules which I don't want to.

Any solutions please?

Answer (score -3):

Using an example, if your `html` property is:

```
<p><img src="cid:c001" /></p>
```

then `attachments` property has to be as follows:

```
[ { path: "data:image/gif;base64,...image data here....",
     cid: "c001"
} ]
```

For additional embedded images, just add them to the `attachments` array.

The above will generate a mail as follows:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="s1"

--s1
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    ...the (plain)`text` part of your message
--s1
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html"; boundary="s2"

--s2
Content-Type: text/html

<p><img src="cid:c001" /></p>
--s2

Content-Type: image/gif; name=attachment-1.gif
Content-ID: <c001>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=attachment-1.gif

...image data here....
--s2
--s1
```